# Magento Exception log

Tags: magento-1.8, log, exception

I am getting the same exception over and over in the log, it actually making the log file very large over time. I'm really not sure how to even begin fixing this:

```
2016-01-14T05:30:34+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product_list.na...')
#3 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product_list.na...')
#4 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/community/MT/Filter/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(49): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): MT_Filter_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

**Here is the Updated extended log:**

```
2016-01-16T03:26:32+00:00 ERR (3): 

Invalid block type: #0 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage->throwException('Invalid block type: ')

#1 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)

#2 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product_list.name.after')

#3 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product_list.name.after')

#4 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element, Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)

#5 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)

#6 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

#7 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

#8 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()

#9 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/local/Mirasvit/SeoFilter/Controller/Router.php(129): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')

#10 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mirasvit_SeoFilter_Controller_Router->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)

#11 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#12 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#13 /chroot/home/vpagec/dev.page.com/html/index.php(87): Mage->run('', 'store')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252560/magento-invalid-block-type

Comment: Thanks, I went through the layout file and I do not have any <block name=

Comment: According to the trace log check the block name started with "product_list.na" in all XML layouts and CMS pages/blocks layout updates in Admin panel. Then remove this block

Answer (score 4):

The message says that you use invalid block somewhere in the code. Stack trace log is cut. It is a PHP fault. How to fix it in Magento refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358464/2720986

Check the trace log near this line

```
#2 /chroot/home/vourwebsitec/ourwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product_list.na...')
```

You'll find there the full block name. Try to find this block name in all XML layout files and CMS pages/blocks layout updates in Admin panel. Then remove this block.

**UPDATE**

According to the full trace log the following block is incorrect: "product_list.name.after".
@Johnnyrt noted in his comment the piece of code

```
<catalog_category_default> 
  <reference name="content"> 
    <block name="product_list.name.after"> 
      <block type="core/template" name="dailydeal.list.countdown" template="dailydeal/list_countdown.phtml" /> 
    </block> 
  </reference> 
</catalog_category_default>
```

`<block name="product_list.name.after">` is incorrect because it hasn't the type attribute. Two ways to solve the problem:

- Remove `<block name="product_list.name.after">`. Care about validity of XML
- Add a type attribute, i.e. "core/text_list": `<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after">`

Check if the the store functionality works as it should after these modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the steps and I will update the questions with the extended log

Comment: Did you try to find the block `product_list.name.after` in XML layout files and layout updates in CMS pages and blocks?

Comment: Found this in our Daily Deal.xml:       

<catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="product_list.name.after">
                <block type="core/template" name="dailydeal.list.countdown" template="dailydeal/list_countdown.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

Comment: The following  record in XML layout <block name="product_list.name.after"> is incorrect because a block should have a 'type' attribute. For example look at this: <block type="core/template" name="dailydeal.list.countdown" template="dailydeal/list_countdown.phtml" /> Please remove that block and keep XML valid. Then check if the error is gone from the log file.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

1. Switch back to native `default/default` Magento theme.
2. If the error is still happening, **disable your non Magento modules one by one to find the module causing the problem**. Once you've found it, look into the related layout file and look for any block tag without a type attribute.
3. If the error is not happening on `default/default` Magento theme, then it is **caused by your custom theme**. Search in your layout files any block tag without a type attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the default, disabled everything, no luck, I still got the same exception.

Comment: Look for a block named "product_list.name.after" in your layout files that's the one breaking your code.